# как создать подобную прямую?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui, ui

у меня есть код:

```
    import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys


def main(k, b, zn):
    if k == 0:
        if zn in ('<=', '<'):
            return 'x є (-∞ ; +∞)'
        else:
            return 'x - будь-яке число'
    else:
        prb = b / k

        if b < 0 or k < 0:
            if zn == '>':
                zn = '<'
            elif zn == '<':
                zn = '>'
            elif zn == '>=':
                zn = '<='
            elif zn == '<=':
                zn = '>='

        if zn == '>=':
            return f'x є [{prb} ; +∞)'
        elif zn == '>':
            return f'x є ({prb} ; +∞)'
        elif zn == '<=':
            return f'x є (-∞ ; {prb}]'
        elif zn == '<':
            return f'x є (-∞ ; {prb})'


def calculate():
    k = float(k_entry.get())
    b = float(b_entry.get())
    zn = zn_entry.get()

    result = main(k, b, zn)
    result_label.config(text=result)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 400)
    y = [k * xi + b if k * xi + b >= 0 else np.nan for xi in x]
    ax.plot(x, y, label=f'y = {k}x + {b}')
    ax.axhline(0, color='black', linewidth=0.5)
    ax.axvline(0, color='black', linewidth=0.5)
    ax.legend()

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=window)
    canvas_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
    canvas_widget.grid(row=4, columnspan=3)


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Рішення лінійних нерівностей")

k_label = tk.Label(window, text="k:")
k_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
k_entry = tk.Entry(window)
k_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

b_label = tk.Label(window, text="b:")
b_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
b_entry = tk.Entry(window)
b_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

zn_label = tk.Label(window, text="Знак нерівності:")
zn_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
zn_entry = tk.Entry(window)
zn_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

calculate_button = tk.Button(window, text="Розрахувати", command=calculate)
calculate_button.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)

result_label = tk.Label(window, text="")
result_label.grid(row=3, column=2)

window.mainloop()
```

вместо графика мне нужно создать прямую, на которой будет отмечаться область допустимых значений x, вот пример: https://ibb.co/7JLb63V, так оно должно отмечаться и такая прямая мне нужна, вот ещё пример, тут, хоть и немного криво, показано задание, которое нужно выполнять: https://ibb.co/JpxnbCr